# Equation 1/(x+1) performance on values of a specific column in bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk, calculator, equation

I have a big CSV file which the head looks like this:

```
ccd_11_0    Gly_GCC_89  2
ccd_11_0    Gly_GCC_87  8
ccd_11_0    Gly_GCC_88  0
ccd_11_1    Gly_GCC_87  1
```

I want to perform the equation 1/(x+1) on the numbers in the third column. So then the output should look like:

```
ccd_11_0    Gly_GCC_89  0.33
ccd_11_0    Gly_GCC_87  0.11
ccd_11_0    Gly_GCC_88  1
ccd_11_1    Gly_GCC_87  0.5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '{$3=1/($3+1)}1' yourfile
```

This is using the default field separator to split your rows up into columns $1, $2, and $3. Then it's just performing the math to set your third column `$3` to the value `1/($3+1)`. At the end it's printing out the results with that `1` (awk shorthand).

Comment: Thank you for your solution. So $3 means column three and I didn't understand what the last ```1``` means?

Comment: @Apex The last 1 is an idiom for 'print the line'.

Comment: awk operates sequentially in the steps/blocks of code. A block generally looks like `{print $4}` for instance to print the 4th column. That might be followed with another step like `{print $4}{var=$5}` and now variable `var` holds the value in column 5. These blocks can be conditional by providing a condition before the block like `{print $4}$5~/^s/{var=$5}` where the variable `var` is set only if the 5th column starts with the letter `s`. If no block exists after a condition the default is to print the line. So the `1` just says `TRUE` and the absence of a block causes the line to print.